# Null Ptr Exception with Bubble Sort in Java

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, linked-list, bubble-sort

I am getting a null pointer exception before I can even get to my code. I cannot tell if it will work correctly cause I can't make it pass this point.

The error is thrown in this line:

```
if(currentNode.getData() > currentNode.getNext().getData())
```

Here is my bubble sort:

```
public static void bubbleSort(DoubleLinkedList list) //static method used to sort the linked list using bubble sort
      {
          int i = 0;
          int j = 0;
          Node currentNode = list.head;
          Node previousNode = currentNode;
          Node tempNext =  currentNode;
          Node tempPrevious = currentNode;


          for(i=1; i<list.getSize(); i++)
          {
              for(j=0; j<list.getSize()-1; j++)
              {
                  if(currentNode.getData() > currentNode.getNext().getData())
                  {
                      if(currentNode == list.head)
                      {
                          Node tempNode = currentNode.getNext();

                          list.head = tempNode;
                          tempNext = tempNode.getNext();

                          tempNode.setNext(currentNode);
                          currentNode.setNext(tempNext);
                          currentNode.setPrevious(tempNode);

                          tempNext.setPrevious(currentNode);
                      }
                      else if(currentNode.getNext() == list.last)
                      {
                          Node tempNode = currentNode.getNext();
                          list.last = currentNode;
                          tempPrevious = currentNode.getPrevious();

                          tempNode.setNext(currentNode);
                          tempNode.setPrevious(tempPrevious);

                          currentNode.setPrevious(tempNode);
                      }
                      else
                      {
                          Node tempNode = currentNode.getNext();
                          tempPrevious = currentNode.getPrevious();
                          tempNext = currentNode.getNext();

                          tempPrevious.setNext(tempNode);
                          tempNext.setPrevious(currentNode);

                          currentNode.setNext(tempNext);
                          tempNode.setPrevious(tempPrevious);
                      }

                  }

                  currentNode = currentNode.getNext();

              }
          }



      }
```

I thought the limits on my loops would keep the compiler from trying to access a pointer that does not necessarily exist which is what I understand a null pointer exception to be.

If anyone could help me get past this error so that I can test my bubble sort I'd be extremely grateful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either `currentNode` is null or `currentNode.getNext()` returns null and that's why you cant call `getData()` on it. You should always check your nodes for null values before you use them.

Comment: i've added in a condition checking to make sure they're not null in the if statement, yet the same error is thrown. Anything else I can do?

Comment: It has to be either of those two being null. That's what NullPointerException means. Or you'll have to check the implementation of your `DoubleLinkedList`. The error may be coming from there. If you are getting this error on that line, then either of the two values is definitely null.

Answer (score 1):

If `currentNode` and `currentNode.getNext()` being or returning `null` don't cause the problem, then I'd guess that the `getData()` methods do not return a primitive data type (like `int`) but an object (like `Integer`).

In this case `getData()` could return `null` and the out-boxing, the automatic conversion of a wrapper class instance to its wrapped primitive type, that is needed for the `<` operation,  would fail and cause a NPE.